# Why do input type="date" and "time" load blank on mobile devices even with a value set?

Tags: android, html, ios, html-input

I'm having an issue where I have two inputs of type date and time that have the value attribute are showing up as blank input boxes.

Example:

```
<input type="date" value="2016-11-11" />
<input type="time" value="11:00" />
```

The code is being run as a website from the mobile device's web browser (ie. safari, chrome, etc.). The value only shows up inside the input box when the user changes it.

Comment: I think you're looking for a [picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Comment: It's a website so I would be using the native datepicker that IOS or Android would use for these types of input. The pickers show up it's just the initial value that I set isn't showing up inside the input box.

Comment: so are you using these in a `webview`?

Comment: It's from the browser not within a mobile application